# Function $f\colon R\to N, x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ Find domain of :D

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Function $$f\colon R\longrightarrow N, x\longmapsto \sqrt{x}$$ Find domain of :D Help me please :D

Comment: Is $R$ supposed to be $\mathbb R$ and $N$ supposed to be $\mathbb N$? If so, this question has serious problems.

Comment: Yes but in my test they write set of real equal to $R$

Comment: I don't even know where to start. This is full of problems. The notation $f\colon R\to N$ already implies that the domain of $f$ is $R$. But $f$ is not defined on all of $R$. Furthermore the codomain is not $N$.

Comment: Okay found the solution, thanks anyway!

Comment: Please indulge me and post your solution as an answer. I'd love to see it.

Comment: So this is equiv. to determining x values such that sqrt(x) is a natural number, which means x must be eq. to n^2 so the domain of f(x) is {x=n^2/n in N}

Comment: Sounds good, but it doesn't solve the problem that the  notation $f\colon R→N$ already implies that the domain of $f$ is $R$.

Comment: My definition of domain: If $f:S->E$ it is the set {x in S/ f(x) in E}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I believe that the "author" of your test had better look for a job in agriculture, my opinion is that they want you to write down *the set of real numbers whose square root is an integer*. It is clear that this set coincides with the set $$\left\{ p^2 \mid p \in \mathbb{Z} \right\},$$ namely the set of squares of (positive and negative) integers.

Comment: Where I come from we use 'fishing' instead of 'agriculture' (+1)

Comment: In Italy we say "arms stolen to agriculture" :-)

Comment: In Portugal we say "he'd do better in focusing on fishing".